# Repeated names in shape file, not allowing to read the file

Tags: r

I am using Simple Features (sf package) for R to read a some shape files.

Due to the length of colnames characters allowed in *.shp files, in an external process while saving spatial information to a *.shp file, some of the original names where truncated and as a result of it two or more columns are having the same name.

Naturally when trying to read such file i am having the following error:

> Error: Column names s_startD, s_startD must not be duplicated. Use
>   **.name_repair** to specify repair

I have not a single idea how to use this **name_repair** function.

Comment: https://rdrr.io/cran/tibble/man/name-repair.html